# UICollectionViewFlowLayout's layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath returns nil when called "too early"

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

My setup:
A standard UICollectionView with a flow layout; datasource is set to my controller.
The layout is configured as usual in the xib file.
When I try to access a cell's layout attributes via layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: in the Controller's viewDidLoad method like so:

```
NSLog(@"LayoutAttribute: %@", [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]);
```

The output is

```
"LayoutAttribute: (null)"
```

even though the layout has all information required to give me the correct layout attributes.
It still does not work in viewWillAppear:, but it "magically" starts working in viewDidAppear:

```
"LayoutAttribute: <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x8c4f710> index path: (<NSIndexPath 0x8c48be0> 2 indexes [0, 0]); frame = (0 0; 50 50);"
```

I discovered a very strange way to make it work; I just access the collectionViewContentSize before requesting the layout attributes:

```
NSLog(@"Layout content size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize));    
NSLog(@"LayoutAttribute: %@", [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]);
```

The output is, as expected all along:

```
"Layout content size: {768, 50}"
"LayoutAttribute: <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x8c4f710> index path: (<NSIndexPath 0x8c48be0> 2 indexes [0, 0]); frame = (0 0; 50 50);"
```

What is going on here? I assume accessing the content size triggers something in the layout, but does anyone know if there is a proper way to do this? Or is this just an annoying bug?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` says that it only returns `nil` if there is no item at that index path. Did you perhaps not call `reloadData` on your collection view before calling `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`?

Another common problem is that some intermediate object in your call chain is `nil`. Perhaps collectionView or collectionView.collectionViewLayout is `nil`?